# Using bootstrap in ajax ConfirmButtonExtender

Tags: asp.net, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I need to have a confirm popup dialog with a button using bootstrap modal. I need to do something easy-to-use for my team, so I utilized ajax ConfirmButtonExtender and did something like this. but its not working. am getting this error "Value cannot be null.Parameter name: control". This is what I did:

```
<button id="btnModal" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Test Confirmation Dialog</button>

<ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="cbe" runat="server" DisplayModalPopupID="mpe" TargetControlID="btnModal">
</ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender>

<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlconfirm" TargetControlID="btnModal" OkControlID="btnSave"
    CancelControlID="btnError">
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlconfirm">
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content form-horizontal">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h2 class="modal-title">Confirmation Message</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>You are about to delete one track url, this procedure is irreversible.</p>
                    <p>Do you want to proceed?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-message">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblModalMessage" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSave" Text="Cancel" CssClass="btn btn-default CausesValidation" />
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnError" Text="Delete" CssClass="btn btn-danger" />
                    <%--<button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>--%>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I didn't mention data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" yet to check weather this will work or not.

Comment: if you are not mentioning these attributes "data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" " then you have to specify an click event to show the model using the $("#myModal).modal("show") method

Comment: @Sahil i am using ModalPopupExtender.